# Why ninject injects a null where it could inject an empty enumerable?

Tags: .net, collections, ienumerable, ninject

I have the following definitions.

```
interface IWeapon {}

class Warrior
{
 [Inject]
 public IEnumerable<IWeapon> Weapons { get; private set; }
}
```

If I call `new StandardKernel().GetAll<IRule>()` it understandably returns an empty enumerable.

Now, if I call `new StandardKernel().Get<Engine>()`, the returned warrior has a `null` in the `Weapons` property. Shouldn't an empty enumerable be injected?

---

A secondary question. I modified the `Warrior` class as following.

```
class Warrior
{
    public IEnumerable<IWeapon> Weapons { get; private set; }

 public Warrior(IEnumerable<IWeapon> weapons)
 { this.Weapons = weapons; }
}
```

This time, if I call `new StandardKernel().Get<Engine>()` Ninject will throw an ActivationException saying that "No matching bindings are available". Again, I was expecting it to just send an empty enumerable.

So, is this behavior really expected by design or is there a bug here? If it's by design, is there any workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a discussion about this and constructor scoring today with Ian. We both agreed that we should change this. Just be a little patient and wait until we have implemented it.

Comment: Nothing like getting an answer direct from the authors. I'll wait for a code change then. Or I'll try to implement it myself. :)

Comment: Added to the latest version. Will be part of the upcomming RC2.